Why did I get different simulation results for the same transistor model in LTspice?
The following is my FM transmitter circuit. In the first simulation, I auto-generated a symbol for BFQ19S.

Replace the auto-generated symbol with the one from default NPN.



In the second simulation, I use .model on the schematics.

The result looks like this.

In real life, I want to use this BFQ19SH6327XTSA1 from Infineon instead of 2N22222. (link datasheet) and download link for lib
***************************************************************
*   Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   GUMMEL-POON MODEL   IN  SPICE   2G6 SYNTAX
*   VALID   UP  TO  6   GHZ
*   >>> BFQ19S  <<<
*   (C) 2014    Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   Version 2.1 October 2014
***************************************************************
*.OPTION TNOM=25, GMIN= 1.00e-12
*BFQ19S C B E
.SUBCKT BFQ19S 11 22 33
*
CBEPAR 2 3 1.941E-014
CBCPAR 2 1 5.476E-013
CCEPAR 1 3 7.843E-013
LB    2 20 2.448E-009
LE   3 30 1.706E-009
Rci 1 10 0.002258
CBEPCK 20 30  8.568E-016
CBCPCK 10 20  1.201E-014
CCEPCK 10 30  8.448E-014
LBX    20 22 7.525E-013
LEX   30 33 1.178E-010
LCX   10 11  2.449E-010
*
*
Q1 1 2 3 M_BFQ19S
*
*
.MODEL  M_BFQ19S    NPN(
+   TNOM    =   25
+   IS  =   1.734E-015
+   BF  =   126.2
+   NF  =   0.9968
+   VAF =   52.15
+   IKF =   1.035
+   ISE =   7.715E-015
+   NE  =   1.81
+   BR  =   13.1
+   NR  =   0.9968
+   VAR =   3.079
+   IKR =   0.1214
+   ISC =   6.257E-015
+   NC  =   1.6
+   RB  =   5.552
+   IRB =   2.4E-005
+   RBM =   1.524
+   RE  =   0.2261
+   RC  =   1.814
+   XTB =   0.854
+   EG  =   1.11
+   XTI =   9.516
+   CJE =   4.551E-012
+   VJE =   0.7397
+   MJE =   0.3271
+   TF  =   2.467E-011
+   XTF =   4.69
+   VTF =   6.79
+   ITF =   1.027
+   PTF =   9.546E-017
+   CJC =   1.164E-012
+   VJC =   0.6791
+   MJC =   0.3983
+   XCJC    =   0.007944
+   TR  =   3.412E-008
+   CJS =   0
+   VJS =   0.3601
+   MJS =   0.02997
+   FC  =   0.567
+   KF  =   2.2E-14
+   AF  =   1.6)
***************************************************************
*
*
.ENDS BFQ19S


Please ask a specific question of where you are stuck, you can't just switch it transistors without matching specs

@VoltageSpike What do you mean "switch it transistors without matching specs"?

Note that the SUBCKT (between the .SUBCKT and .ENDS cards) contains the statements,
Q1 1 2 3 M_BFQ19S
*
*
.MODEL  M_BFQ19S    NPN(
...

Presumably, the model you used was the same, however the SUBCKT has other stuff with it.  We can match up the local net names to see what.
The SUBCKT is declared with three terminals, connecting internal nets 11, 22 and 33.
Two-terminal components are declared with a designator (the first letter dictates component type), two nodes, and a value or model (and other optional parameters after that).  We find 33 for example connects to 30 via LEX (presumably inductor, emitter, ...xtra?).  And then 30 to 3 with LE, and Q1 is declared C-B-E-model so 3 is the internal emitter connection.  And all the capacitors (between BJT terminals, and between 10s inner nets), and that's about it.
It's a package parasitic SPICE model.  Values of single to fractional nH are typical of pin and wirebond inductance, and fractional pF, of capacitance between pins and through the package.
Using the SUBCKT is most accurate to the real component.  Still merely an approximation, but likely to be more correct over a wide frequency range (and note they give a quite generous 6GHz range -- yes, they even specify!).
Given relevant concerns raised in your previous question, including packaging parasitics is likely to meaningfully improve the accuracy of the circuit model -- but don't stop there, find models for other components (yes, even resistors and capacitors!), and estimates for trace inductance and coupling.

What is LEX and LE? are both of them some parasitic inductance of package?

I would say all statements from lines 13 to 24 are package parasitics. At low frequencies, series elements add together and can be totaled that way, yes.
